# How do I render all pages in a page collection on one page?

Tags: handlebars.js, gruntjs, assemble

I'm trying to figure out how to render all the pages in a page collection on a single page. I want all my posts after each other in the generated `index.html`, like on a blog's front page.

The file structure is

```
src/
  index.hbs
  posts/
    post-1.hbs
    post-2.hbs
    post-3.hbs
```

The below does almost what I'm looking for.

```
<section>
{{#each pages}}
  <article>
    <header>
      <h2>{{data.title}}</h2>
    </header>
    {{page}}
  </article>
{{/each}}
</section>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3):

*Excuse the quick and dirty answer, I wanted to get it up here as quickly as possible. I'll clean it up in a day or two. (2013-09-26)*

After working on this I ended up making a Handlebars helper that I could use in the `index.hbs` template. With it, I end up with the below Handlebars template for `index.hbs`.

**index.hbs**

```
---
title: Home
---
<p>I'm a dude. I live in Stockholm, and most of the time I work with <a href="http://www.gooengine.com/">Goo</a>.</p>

<section>
  {{#md-posts 'src/posts/*.*'}}
  <article>
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    {{#markdown}}
      {{{body}}}
    {{/markdown}}
  </article>
  {{/md-posts}}
</section>
```

**Folder structure**

```
src/
  index.hbs
  posts/
    post-1.hbs
    post-2.hbs
    post-3.md // <--- Markdown with Handlebars
```

**Gruntfile.coffee**

```
assemble:
  options:
    flatten: true
    layout: 'layouts/default.hbs'
    assets: 'public/assets'
    helpers: 'src/helpers/helper-*.js'
  root: // this is my target
    src: 'src/*.hbs' // <--- Only assemble files at source root level
    dest: 'public/'
```

**src/helpers/helper-md-posts.js**

This helper takes a glob expression, reads the files, extracts the YAML front matter, compiles the body source, and finally adds it all to the Handlebars block context. *The helper is somewhat misnames, as it doesn't actually compile Markdown... so naming suggestions are welcome.*

```
var glob = require('glob');
var fs = require('fs');
var yamlFront = require('yaml-front-matter');

module.exports.register = function(Handlebars, options) {

  // Customize this helper
  Handlebars.registerHelper('md-posts', function(str, options) {

    var files = glob.sync(str);
    var out = '';
    var context = {};
    var data = null;
    var template = null;

    var _i;
    for(_i = 0; _i < files.length; _i++) {
      data = yamlFront.loadFront(fs.readFileSync(files[_i]), 'src');

      template = Handlebars.compile(data.src); // Compile the source

      context = data; // Copy front matter data to Handlebars context
      context.body = template(data); // render template

      out += options.fn(context);
    }

    return out;
  });

};
```

---

See it all in this repo: https://github.com/marcusstenbeck/marcusstenbeck.github.io/tree/source

Comment: hey @Marcus, nice work on the helper and finding a solution to this. For the name of the helper, how about `inline`? since that's technically what you're doing. also if you want to do a pull request with this helper to the [handlebars-helpers](https://github.com/assemble/handlebars-helpers) library I'd be happy to merge it.

Comment: @jonschlinkert, are you suggesting a rename from _md-posts_ to _inline_? I'd be happy to make a pull-request, and it'll also be my first open-source contrib. It's a good day today. :)

Comment: "rename from md-posts to inline" correct. :-) we're a friendly crowd, I'd be happy to help if you have any questions with your first contribution!

Comment: @jonschlinkert Alright, I'll take a stab at it and then send a PR your way. Is this grounds for cracking a bottle of Cristal, or more of a micro-brew type of moment?

Comment: @jonschlinkert How do I do with documentation?

Comment: ha! it's grounds for celebration, I think you can't go wrong with either ;-)  as for docs, don't worry about that, I'll put something together based on this. however, to avoid collision I would change "body" to something else, like "content". also, you can even add the helper to a new file in the ./lib directory if you want. we're in the process of reorganizing them anyway, so I won't lose sleep over it

Comment: @jonschlinkert You've got a PR. I edited the vars to map better to what's in the Pages Collections usage examples.  http://assemble.io/docs/Pages-Collections.html :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38125/discussion-between-marcusstenbeck-and-jonschlinkert)